# Calling two web services at the same time Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to make a weather app that calls current weather data and 5 days forecast data at the same time and put both of web service datas in one card. Do i have to use async task or can I simply call two web services one after another and add them to request queue in the service file? Can you help me to find the best way please?

Comment: Are using any library for calling Web Service?

Comment: If you can, kindly add some code in your question.